# C# - Console.ReadLine() not working in exe file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cmd, rider

I tried to compile my C# Solution to a .exe file. I am currently working with Idea Rider and I executed the automatically generated Output in /bin/... .

However when I run the file by double-clicking it, or by executing it manually in the terminal or by .bat file it doesn't prompt for an input as expected.

My code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Renci.SshNet;

namespace VLAN_Switcher
{
    class DeploymentMode
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string laboratory = "";
            while (!laboratory.Equals("76") && !laboratory.Equals("61") && !laboratory.Equals("101"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In welches VLAN soll der LehrerPC gegeben werden(61,76 oder 101)?:");
                laboratory = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            string localIP = FindIp();
            ChangePortToNewLaboratory(localIP, laboratory);
            ChangeIP(localIP, laboratory);
        }

        public static string FindIp()
        {
            string localIP;
            using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
            {
                socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
                IPEndPoint endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
                localIP = endPoint.Address.ToString();
                return localIP;
            }
        }

        public static void ChangePortToNewLaboratory(string localIP, string laboratory)
        {
            string currentVLAN = localIP.Split(".")[2];
            //Connection information
            string host = $"";
            int port = 22;
            string username = "";
            string password = "";
            
            using (var client = new SshClient(host, port, username, password))
            {
                client.Connect();
                ShellStream shellStream = client.CreateShellStream(string.Empty, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                shellStream.Write("en\n");
                shellStream.Write("conf t\n");
                shellStream.Write("interface GigabitEthernet1/0/48\n");
                shellStream.Write($"switchport access vlan {laboratory}\n");
                shellStream.Close();
                client.Disconnect();
            }
        }

        public static void ChangeIP(string localIP, string laboratory)
        {
            NetworkInterface interfaceLan = null;
            string[] ipAddressArr = localIP.Split(".");
            ipAddressArr[2] = laboratory;
            string newIpAddress = String.Join(".",ipAddressArr);
            ipAddressArr[3] = "254";
            string newGateway = String.Join(".",ipAddressArr);

            foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.ToString() == localIP)
                        { 
                            interfaceLan = ni;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            var process = new Process
            {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", $"interface ip set address \"{interfaceLan}\" static {newIpAddress} 255.255.255.0" + (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newGateway) ? "" : $"{newGateway} 1")) { Verb = "runas" }
                };
            process.Start();
            process.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the main function - somehow this Console.ReadLine() doesn't get excecuted:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string laboratory = "";
            while (!laboratory.Equals("76") && !laboratory.Equals("61") && !laboratory.Equals("101"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In welches VLAN soll der LehrerPC gegeben werden(61,76 oder 101)?:");
                laboratory = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            string localIP = FindIp();
            ChangePortToNewLaboratory(localIP, laboratory);
            ChangeIP(localIP, laboratory);
        }
```

Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">      

    <PropertyGroup>         
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>          
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>         
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>         
        <RootNamespace>VLAN_Switcher</RootNamespace>         
        <ApplicationIcon>Herunterladen.ico</ApplicationIcon>     
    </PropertyGroup>      

    <ItemGroup>       
        <PackageReference Include="SSH.NET" Version="2020.0.2" />     
    </ItemGroup>  

</Project>
```

Maybe I am executing the file in a wrong way, but I can't find any other way.

Thanks in advance!

Lorenz

Comment: Put breakpoints in your code and DEBUG.

Comment: Did you setup your project as console app?

Comment: @Selvin yes it is a Console App.

Comment: @PoulBak how can I put breakpoints in an .exe file

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? then click in the left margin of your code. Then run.

Comment: @PoulBak when I run it in Visual Studio or Idea Rider it works just fine. However as soon as I run the file as an exe it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Provide project file...

Comment: @Selvin just did. Please look at the question

Comment: `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>` He he he he console app... No, not at all

Comment: Should be: `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the output type in my .csproject file.

It was:

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

Now it is:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```